# Send result from DialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In dialog I use next extension to send result

```
fun <T : Any> Fragment.setNavigationResult(
    result: T, key: String,
    navController: NavController = findNavController()
) {
    navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

in fragment to get result

```
fun <T>Fragment.getNavigationResult(@IdRes id: Int, key: String, onResult: (result: T) -> Unit) {
    val navBackStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(id)

    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME && navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.contains(key)) {
            val result = navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.get<T>(key)
            result?.let(onResult)
            navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.remove<T>(key)
        }
    }
    navBackStackEntry.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            navBackStackEntry.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    })
}
```

but I get crash like this:
[image]

Somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native solution of Fragment which uses `fragmentManager` instead of `backstackEntry`.

Please check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result